# Replacing blank values in a field using Calculate Field in ArcGIS ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.5, replace

I'm using ArcGIS 10.5 and working with geodatabase layers.

My previous step was only a union between my area of study layer (which has no info in its table) and another layer with the soil cover. The resulting layer took the COVER field of the second layer, but the parts where both layers did not overlap are now polygons in which the COVER field is blank, and I need to change it to "Urban".

I could update them manually by selecting and using Field Calculator, but I'd like to be able to do this step inside ModelBuilder so it is automated. I found the sequences to replace strings using Calculate Field, both for VBSCript and Python, but what gives me trouble is the part where I tell the tool **what to find**, the ones below with the xxxx:

```
replace([COVER], "xxxx", "Urban")
```

```
!COVER!.replace("xxxx", "Urban")
```

What I don't know is what iI should type to tell the tool that it should look only for blank cells in that particular field (there is not a single NULL). I tried putting a space between the ", not putting anything at all, just writing blank, NULL, typing a "-", etc, but none worked. Many simply don't change anything, and other such as typing a space change the spaces between the words in the rest of my other cells (but not the blank ones), which that should not be changed.

My current sequence (copy/pasted a it is) is the following, maybe something else is wrong?

```
!COVER!.replace("", "Urban")
```

What should I write in the formula so that it replaces only the blank cells?

Comment: try with single quote

Comment: I already did, the results are exactly the same as using double quote.

Comment: I tried and get the same behavior as you (no error but the empty cell are not replaced no matter what), the only way I can think of is to add a select empty cell step in your model then update the selected cell (won't simplify your model but at last could be automated) ..

Comment: I thought about doing so but I got some new problems. The _Select_ tool exports the selected data, which I don't want to, and the _Select Layer by Attribute_, for some reason, doesn't allow me to select the layer that should be updated. Also, simplifying the model is not something I care at all for now.